# How to create namespace packages in Python?

Tags: python, namespaces, package, distutils

I have a Python 3 project with the following structure:

```
project/
|
+--root/
   |
   +--__init__.py
   |
   +--sub/
      |
      +--__init__.py
      |
      +--actualcode.py
```

I want to use "namespace packages" so that my lib shares a common namespace with other related libs in separate projects. The import statement should look like this:

```
from root.sub.actualcode import something
```

The `__init__.py` file in the root folder contains the following statement to create a namespace package:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

But I cannot reference the code when I import `root.sub`. It works only when I write:

```
from sub.actualcode import something # doesn't work with "root.sub..."!
```

What should I do to use `root` as a namespace?

Comment: Are the namespace properly defined in the setup.py of your package?

Comment: distutils don't have a porperty to configure namespace in setup.py. http://docs.python.org/py3k/distutils/setupscript.html

Comment: Nobody cares about distutils. setuptools or distribute is the way to got

Comment: @Sentinel Thanks for the hint. Following the distutils doc it should work, but maybe distribute is better. It has direct [namespace support.](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Namespace packages can be built with [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages). The trick is then to add the following line to the parameter of `setup`:

```
setup(
  # ...
  namespace_packages  = ["root"]
)
```

The rest of the example in the question is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried your example, but it seems to work like you want it to:

```
    >>> from root.sub.actualcode import foo
    >>> foo()
    Bar!
```

I ran the Python interpreter from the directory containing the `root` folder. I created the empty `__init__.py` files and my `actualcode.py` looks like this:

```
    #!/bin/python3

    def foo():
        print("Bar!")
```

The difference is that my `__init__.py` files are empty.

Comment: But that would not work with another project with the same root namespace.

Comment: Ok, so this solution wors for the case posted here but is not the general solution you tried to find.

Comment: The important detail is the "namespace package".