# Can two distributions deliver the same package?

Tags: python

I am the author of a [PyPi package (or distribution, whatever) called "rewind"](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rewind). It ships a (root) package called `rewind`.

Currently, the `rewind` package contains both server and client code. However, I am considering splitting the code into two separate PyPi packages. One delivering, a `rewind.server` package and the other delivering `rewind.client`.

My question is, **can two separate PyPi packages deliver the same (root) package, `rewind`?**

The test that I've done so far seems to tell me it's not possible. My test created two folders that are prepended to PYTHONPATH. Both folders contain the Python package "mytestpackage". The first "mytestpackage" contains module "a", the second contain module "b". I can only import either module "a" or "b". Not both.

I'd love to hear from fellow Pythonistas if this is possible. Or, is this a limitation of the current Python package implementation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create namespace packages in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568223/how-to-create-namespace-packages-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can, but you need to put a special piece of code in the `rewind/__init__.py` file in each package to declare it a namespace:

```
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
```

and you need to declare the namespace in each package's `setup.py` metadata:

```
setup(
    # ...
    namespace_packages  = ["rewind"]
)
```

All this requires you to use `setuptools`, it will not work with mere distutils distributions.

See the [Namespace packages](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#namespace-packages) documentation of `setuptools`.

Note: older packages used a more verbose version of the namespace declaration code:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

The `declare_namespace()` function now takes care of the same job more concisely.

Comment: Out of curiousity, if you have a namespace package and add code into both rewind/__init__.py. Will both be executed? One of them be executed? Or neither of them?

Comment: Oh, I can answer my own question; Neither of them. It says here: http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#namespace-packages